# end="" parameter doesn't work on Sublimetext 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, sublimetext3

i've tried to use in sublimetext 3 the print("hello", end='') and it says invalid syntax
that's the code:

```
y = 0
while y < 14:
    y+=1
    for i in range(1,4):
        y+=1
print(y, end="")
```

everything else works fine.

Comment: Are you actually using Python 3? Does Sublime Text know that?

Comment: Indeed you are almost certainly running afoul of how the built in build system for Python executes `python`, which on many systems is Python 2 and not Python 3.

Comment: @OdatNurd thank you, indeed I was actually using python2. I built a system for python 3 and it worked.